# I get empty value in the params when I try to create join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, model-associations

I'm creating a join model Invite for has_many through relationship with Party and Guest but I get empty params[:party_id]. The user is logged in as a guest and the guest can see all the party list, and the guest can click individual party and there is a link to join the party. Once the guest click the "Join this party", it goes to '/parties/2/invites/new' and I have a form for the guest to fill out. I get stuck when the guest submit the form. The url changed to '/parties/2/invites' but I still see the form view and once I refresh the page, it shows the invites index page.

I put binding.pry in the invites#create and type params, I can see the party_is "". and I see "commit"=>"Join!", "controller"=>"invites", "action"=>"create", "party_id"=>"3"} permitted: false>.

```
def new
    @invite = Invite.new
    @party_id = params[:party_id]

  end

  def create
    @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
    binding.pry
    if @invite.save

       redirect_to guest_invites_path(current_user)
    else
      @party = Party.find(params[:party_id])
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def invite_params
    params.require(:invite).permit(:add_on, :rsvp, :guest, :party_id)
  end
```

```
<%= form_with model: @invite, url: [@party, @invite], local: true do |f| %>
<%= f.label :add_on, "Add On" %>
<%= f.select :add_on, [1, 2, 3, 4], :prompt => 'Select One' %><br>

<%= f.label :rsvp, "RSVP" %>
<%= f.select :rsvp, [['Yes', true], ['No', false]], :include_blank => true %>

<%= f.hidden_field :party_id, :value => @party_id %>

<%= f.submit "Join!" %>
<% end %>
```

```
class Invite < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :party
    belongs_to :guest

    validates :add_on, :rsvp, presence: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :guest, :party
end
```

[4] pry(#)> raise params.inspect
RuntimeError: "68nwEzR31GS2mcJGq9WhUrP0sp9zSjZENqY4/iosH8sn0zHRxz+PRXXWsQVJDG100FTc+dG4epdA/Cr1DsiRbQ==", "invite"=>"1", "rsvp"=>"true", "party_id"=>""} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Join!", "controller"=>"invites", "action"=>"create", "party_id"=>"3"} permitted: false>
from (pry):4:in `create'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make some changes to your code

From your form, **remove** this line

```
<%= f.hidden_field :party_id, :value => @party_id %>
```

and then in your controller **rewrite** your `create` method to this

```
def create
  @party = Party.find(params[:party_id])
  @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
  @invite.party_id = @party.id 
  if @invite.save

    redirect_to guest_invites_path(current_user)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

So, since your URL already has `party_id`, you don't need to enter it in your form. Try this and let me know!

Comment: I tried that too and it returned nil. I just changed a couple code. Could you please take a look at it again?This time it doesn't return as an empty string but when I submit, @invite doesn't save..

Comment: @Juny_mc I have edited my answer, try it and let me know.

Comment: I fixed it! It was because the hidden_field was under `f`. So the party_id was nested like `params[:invite][:party_id]`. so I changed the hidden_field to `hidden_field_tag` and add `@invite.guest = current_user` in the controller and worked!! Thank you for trying to help me! I added the other two lines from your code as well to make it work. :)

Comment: @Juny_mc Glad it helped! You can accept the answer if it was helpful! Thanks